# Lubuntu 18 won't let me start Windows

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, windows-10

First, my apologies if the question has already been answered but I looked and didn't find anything that completely answered me. And thanks to those who'll answer.

My problem is not only about starting Windows after Ubuntu was installed: they were installed on separate disks.

First off, I use a Dell Vostro. I got it with Windows 10 and a 250 Go SSD and thought I'd add some space, so I added a 1T SSD on which I wanted to install Lubuntu.
The new SSD was recognized by Windows, no problem. Then I made my Lubuntu USB, tried Lubuntu which ran great. And I tried installing, four times.

The installer didn't see Windows and only proposed to erase everything. When I asked for "something else", my original SSD didn't exist there.
Then I read about how to partition a disk on the installer and followed these instructions : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace.

Now Lubuntu was installed fine (on the 1T SSD) and runs without trouble, but I can't access Windows unless I disconnect my 1T SSD (I tried it, Windows is still there and runs when only the 250G SSD is on). I tried hitting F12 while the computer boots and using Windows Boot Manager instead of Lubuntu, but it acts as if Windows was missing entirely.

What can I do to make this work? Not afraid of reinstalling Lubuntu some other way if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: I would recommend using "Boot Repair".

Comment: @karel, I thought maybe it could be more linked to the SSD recognition problem than booting itself.

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165001/is-that-ok-dual-boot-with-two-different-firmwarewinodws-vs-linux-between-uefi/1165020#1165020

Answer (score 1):

Where did you install the boot loader: on the Windows or Linux disk? Choose the Linux disk.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/95kcyw/dualboot_windows_10_and_linux_on_two_hard_drives/

I had another more explanatory source, but having trouble finding it again. Will edit when I do so.

Edit: 
This is the answer which made me install the boot loader on my Linux disk:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1172896#p1172896.

Similar: https://askubuntu.com/a/749354/903128.